# Python packages and import - no module named xy

Tags: python, package

I'm trying to structure my project like this

```
app/
__init__.py
web/
    __init__.py
    web.py
database/
    __init__.py
    db.py
```

I just want to import several classes from `db.py` to `web.py` but just a `ImportError: No module named` is thrown. What I tried so far

web.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
    from database.db import ClassA
OR

from __future__ import absolute_import
from app.database.db import ClassA

OR

from __future__ import absolute_import
import database import ClassA
```

What do I missing?

// edit:

```
db/__init __.py
from db import ClassA
```

All other `__init__.py` are empty. I guess I'm doing something wrong on this.

Comment: What's in your ____init____.py?

Comment: Check my edits @ Torxed

Comment: See my solution, Python2.7 working perfectly, since you didn't mention what version you're using i whent ahead and wrote an example that complies with most users (python 2.X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
C:\pytest\
   test.py
   \database\
       db.py
       __init__.py
   \subfolder\
       __init__.py
       coolios.py
```

where `__init__.py` contains:

```
from db import *
```

and the second `__init__.py` contains:

```
from coolios import *
```

and `db.py` contains:

```
class WHAM():
    def __init__(self):
        print 'You import me!'
```

and `coolios.py` contains:

```
from database import *

class ganster():
    def __init__(self):
        WHAM()
```

and `test.py` contains:

```
from subfolder import ganster
ganster()
```

It should work.

Comment: This works for this example yes. But I want to call WHAM not from a subfolder/package. See my post for my current structre

Comment: See my update, the default "method" is still possible since the imports are made from the root working directory by default, so as long as you don't mess around with chwd() or anything like that, you can from other modules (folders) do `from FOLDER import *` and then call the functions you would expect to be able to call. It expands to `from /FOLDER/ import <definitions in __init__.py>`

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
from ..database import db
```

You can also check the importings by running the `web.py` from the root of your project

```
python -m app.web.web
```

Comment: wouldn't this be a relative import in this case?

Comment: yup, it is called relative import. You can also set your project folder into your python path, but i do not like that way much since it could lead to conflict to other python packages

Comment: Your answer gives now this: ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: I have to go back now (it s 6 PM here already). For your case, try make some simple python packages / folders and play with the importing, you will see the result, say `demo/main.py, demo/__init__.py, demo/a/a.py, demo/a/__init__.py, demo/b/b.py, demo/b/__ini__.py` with `a` import from `b` and run the project from `main` (which call `a`) to see if it works. Remember to change dir out of the demo folder and run `python -m demo.main`. Good luck

Comment: I think I've got I figured it out: I runned the code from IDEA directly the web.py. If I move a python file to my top-package eg. root folder and import the web stuff from there it executes.